# PHPMailer error: "unable to connect to :25"

Tags: php, phpmailer

When I was trying to send an email using the PHPMailer class, I had the following error:

> Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to :25 (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. ) in C:\Users\Testing\Downloads\PHPMailer\phpmailer\class.smtp.php on line 105

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

`unable to connect to :25` is an indication that you forgot to enter a server address in the configuration.

Make sure you are specifying a valid SMTP server address when initializing PHPMailer.